# EXISTS subquery causes error 1064

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, exists

since my last PLESK Update to 12.0.18 #70, I have a problem with phpMyAdmin using select statements with **EXISTS subqueries**.

If I take simply the example from the MariaDB website (I tested it with real tables and fields on my DB):

```
SELECT col1 FROM t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t2)
```

Quickly the interpreter underlines "*EXISTS*" and the "*(SELECT*" to show the error 1064

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

1.  unknown keyword (near "EXISTS" at position 30)
2.  unexpected character (near "(" at position 37)
```

Important to know: The Select statements works fine on my MariaDB (10.0.20) server using PHP code. Only phpMyAdmin tells me that there is a syntax error.

Is EXISTS depricated?

Thank you!

[phpMyAdmin 4.5.0.2 and MariaDB]

Comment: Please post your real query here.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, you're saying the error 1064 appears immediately after you enter the text -- before you actually submit the query with the "Go" button?

Comment: Yes Isaac, you're right! The error appears immediately after typing the query. The error is highlighted immediately with red underlines.
So it doesn't matter if I post the real query here, or this sample query.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem; which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Can you reproduce on http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master ?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch phpMyAdmin is 4.5.0.2. I can't reproduce it on demo. But I am using MariaDB 10.0.22 ! Here is a pic which show the error: https://picload.org/image/piawgaw/exists.png

Answer (score 0):

That was part of an unfortunate series of bugs with the 4.5.0(.x) releases. The latest version is currently 4.5.2 and this bug has been fixed in that version; I suggest that you [upgrade](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version).

Comment: @Issac  YES, you are right. Today I installed an update on PLESK and with it, it installed phpMyAdmin 4.5.1. Bug has been fixed. Thank you for this hint!