# Why does my SQL query return keyword not found

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to retrieve all houses where there is no reservation connected to a certain "huisnummer" (housenumber).

```
SELECT * FROM huis WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * FROM reservering WHERE reservering.huisnummer = huis.huisnummer)
```

When I execute the code in my localhost phpMyAdmin I get an error:

```
Keyword does not recognize. (near "not" at position 25)
Keyword does not recognize. (near "EXISTS" at position 29)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 35)

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Comment: The query does not match the error message

Comment: mysql and mysqli do execute the same command, so there is no difference between them. anyway, from your error message I can clearly see, that you did not post the complete sql command you execute. please copy the exact command you execute towards here, unless we cant help.

Comment: What is your Phpmyadmin version? There is a related [BUG](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11680) corrected only on phpmyadmin 4.5.2. Related questions: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690488/exists-subquery-causes-error-1064?rq=1) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919209/not-exists-considered-as-a-syntax-error?rq=1)

Comment: To test if this is a phpmyadmin issue try running the query from commmand line sql.

Comment: @juergend The `LIMIT 0, 25` part is probably added to the original query by phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known phpmyadmin bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11680) that fails to handle queries with EXISTS.

Make sure you install the version 4.5.2 or higher of phpmyadmin.